# Select next 1000

Tags: select, axapta, x++, dynamics-ax-2012

In the ax there is a key word
[*firstOnly1000*](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dynamicsax-2012/developer/select-statement-syntax)

Which can be used like

```
select firstonly1000 <ObjectName> where <where clause>
```

Is there a way how to make a select of the next 1000? I was thinking about using *recid* and

```
select firstonly1000 <ObjectName> where <where clause> && Recid > maxof(firstonly1000.Recid)
```

but in some Ax versions Recid can be lower than zero. Is there some reasonable general way to do this for all Ax versions?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I would say no. And if you're wanting to do some sort of pagination you can use a [query object (see link)](http://axaptadevmallik.blogspot.com/2013/10/code-to-implement-paging-in-ax-2012.html) or something similar to the below X++, which is pretty much the common convention.

```
while select salesTable
{
    i++;
    if (i>1000)
        break;
    info(strFmt("%1: %2", i, salesTable.SalesId));
}
```

Or

```
// Less often used method below. Usually for a specific purpose.
select salesTable;
while (salesTable && i < 1000)
{
    i++;
    info(strFmt("%1: %2", i, salesTable.SalesId));

    next salesTable;
}
```

I would think the simplest way to accomplish what you're trying with the `RecId` would be to sort by `RecId Asc` then just track the last `RecId` that you selected instead of `maxOf`. I'd think you may get poor performance though if you just arbitrarily did it on any table.